# Office 2019 for Mac - Smiley feedback icon overlapped by Search field!

Tags: mac, ms-office

**Office 2019 for Mac - Smiley feedback icon overlapped by Search field!!!**

Affecting all Office applications with such smile face icon in the top-right corner of the Quick Access Toolbar: Excel, Outlook, PowerPoin and Word.

Screen captures showing the issue:

1. Word 2019 Mac - Smile (Smiley) feedback icon **SHOWING-OK** on top-right corner:

[image]

2. Word 2019 Mac - Smile (Smiley) feedback icon **MISSING-OVERLAPPED by SEARCH BOX** on top-right corner:

[image]

How to fix it? **Where does the Quick Access Toolbar of Office 2019 for Mac live in the disk? I mean, in which file? I ask because this issue has arisen on one Mac but not in others, so I could replace such contents or use a backup copy before the issue arose**.

Office 16.28.0 (19081202) on macOS 10.12.6 (16G2128) Sierra, albeit the issue arose with the previous Office version 16.27.0 (19071500) or before.

Comment: Does the answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-2019-for-mac-smiley-feedback-icon/01418114-4619-4e9e-8a96-17fc0fb733e2) not help?

Comment: Thanks, but that is not an answer, but an issue report like here.